# Write RDD[entity] in cassandra from Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to write an RDD that contains public classes in Cassandra with Spark

```
class Test(private var id: String, private var randomNumber: Integer, private var lastUpdate: Instant) {
        def setId(id: String): Unit = { this.id = id }
        def getId: String = { this.id }
        def setLastUpdater(lastUpdater: Instant): Unit = { this.lastUpdater = lastUpdater }
        def getLastUpdater: Instant = { this.lastUpdater }
        def setRandomNumber(number: Integer): Unit = { this.randomNumber = randomNumber }
        def getRandomNumber: Integer = { this.randomNumber }
}
```

This class has all the Setters and Getters to maintain the encapsulation and I need it to not be a Case Class because I have to modify the values during the transformations.

The table corresponding to this entity in Cassandra has slightly different names for the fields:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.test (
  id uuid,
  random_number int,
  last_update timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I am trying to write this RDD with the method `saveToCassandra`

```
implicit val connector = CassandraConnector(sc.getConf)
val rdd: RDD[Test]
rdd.saveToCassandra("test", "test")
```

but the method throws me an exception for the coincidence of the names of the attributes of the class with the names of the fields in the table

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Columns not found in entity.Test: [id, random_number, last_update]
at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:277)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.mapper.DefaultColumnMapper.columnMapForWriting(DefaultColumnMapper.scala:106)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.mapper.MappedToGettableDataConverter$$anon$1.<init>(MappedToGettableDataConverter.scala:35)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.mapper.MappedToGettableDataConverter$.apply(MappedToGettableDataConverter.scala:26)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.DefaultRowWriter.<init>(DefaultRowWriter.scala:16)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.DefaultRowWriter$$anon$1.rowWriter(DefaultRowWriter.scala:30)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.DefaultRowWriter$$anon$1.rowWriter(DefaultRowWriter.scala:28)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$.apply(TableWriter.scala:433)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$.apply(TableWriter.scala:417)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions.saveToCassandra(RDDFunctions.scala:35)
```

how can I write the entity in Cassandra **without having to call the attributes the same** and **the attributes are private** in the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`saveToCassandra` allows you to provide an optional `ColumnSelector`:

```
  def saveToCassandra(
    keyspaceName: String,
    tableName: String,
    columns: ColumnSelector = AllColumns,
    writeConf: WriteConf = WriteConf.fromSparkConf(sparkContext.getConf))(...): Unit
```

In your case you could use the following selector:

```
def selector = SomeColumns(
  ColumnName("id"),
  ColumnName("random_number", alias = Some("randomNumber")),
  ColumnName("last_update", alias = Some("lastUpdate"))
)
```

Btw, while not the typical (and recommended) use of a case class, you could absolutely define fields as `var`s and benefit from using a typed Dataset. That makes it very easy to rename fields before writing to Cassandra.

Comment: This solution solves the problem of having different names in the entity and in the table, but it does not solve the problem of having the attributes of the private class to maintain the encapsulation. ¡This will only be useful if all your attributes are public!

Comment: For your above example `Test` class, the Scala compiler will create internal private fields regardless of the modifier you are providing. However, if private, no setters/getters will be generated. The Cassandra column mapper requires public Scala setters / getters to work. If you insist on keeping `private` there, I fear you're running against a wall. Here's a recommended read on the topic: https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2756472&seqNum=2

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that basic concept, nice reading. Now your solution will be very useful for me.